# How to add an onclick scroll to top in addition to an existing code on button

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

I have a page that can be quite long, where it lists certain data with a "view" button next to these items. I would like to incorporate an onclick scroll to top of page at the same time (hopefully this makes sense).

My current code is:

```
$param = $row['gegevenID'] . '&lvmID=' . $row['luchtvaartmaatschappijID'];
echo "
<td bgcolor='", $row_color, "'>
  <input class   = 'gegevens' 
         type    = 'button' 
         value   = 'View' 
         onclick = 'maps.location.href=\"maps/lvmmap.php?q=", $param, "\"'>
</td>";
```

The reference to `maps.location.href` is an iframe that is at the top of the page. My script does change the map to view the data as appropriate, but I just can't figure out how to make it scroll up, also.

I've had good success with this script on other pages.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="parent.window.scrollTo(0,0);">TOP</a>
```

Comment: If it's an iframe you might not have access to `parent.window`.

Comment: hi hakre. thanks for the response. i should clarify. the button is on a main page, but the onclick changes focus of a map that sits within an iframe. when i click the button, i want it to scroll to the top of the parent page (not the iframe).

Comment: So all you ask is to do two things when the button is clicked? 1.) maps.location.href and 2.) scrollTo(0,0) in the main window? Do I understand this right now?

Comment: then add it behind a semicolon: `onclick = 'window.scrollTo(0,0); maps.location.href=\"ma ...`. javascript can execute more than one command ;)

Comment: thanks for that.. that was a little too easy to be true... works like a charm. thanks for your help.

Comment: lol, okay, yeah, I actually had problems to understand your problem in the first place. I normally suggest that when asking a question to write the example from scratch with as little code as necessary (e.g. getting two alerts with one click or similar). this is normally then easy to understand for others and generally a good practice to write a programming question. There is also jsfiddle for that which is kinda fun. http://jsfiddle.net/